# Asp.Net Core 2.0: Razor view isn't matching a string id route

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This line only works when my id is numeric.

```
<a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a>
```

On one page I need it to be a string.

When it is a number it is generated as

```
<a href="/Users/Edit/1234">Edit</a>
```

But when it is a string it is generated as

```
<a href="">Edit</a>
```

I tried hardcoding the value like this `<a href="/Users/Edit/1234">Edit</a>`, but it just got a 404.

I am using the default routing with my ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor page...

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id}");

        });
```

And the edit page is set up like...

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In case of string simply use:
@page "{id?}

and you should be able to retrieve the value of id (string) in respective method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of my edit page was the line...

```
@page "{id:int}"
```

I had to change this to

```
@page "{id:alpha}"
```

and at that point the route was matched.

Thank you to this page https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-razor-pages/ by Matthew P Jones, which gave an easy to understand explanation of routing with the new Razor pages.

Comment: In my version it was only working with `@page "{id}"`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of string simply use:
@page "{id?}

and you should be able to retrieve the value of id (string) in respective method.